# How unistall glibc 2.35 installed in Ubuntu 20.04.5?

Tags: glibc

Thanks for reading my topic.

I had tried start the Bforartists-3.5.0-linux

but not start and show error message

```
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /opt/bforartists-3.5.0-linux/lib/libcycles_kernel_oneapi_aot.so)
```

However Ubuntu 20.04.5 the libc6 last updated version available is 2.31.

Thus I had downloaded glibc2.35 from
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.35.tar.xz
and after the commands with the file glibc-2.32.tar.gz in /tmp/3/glibc

```
mkdir glibc

cd glibc

tar -xf glibc-2.35.tar.xz

sudo apt install gawk bison libsigsegv2 m4


mkdir build

mkdir glibc-2.35-install

cd build

/tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35/configure --prefix=$tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35-install
```

make

If is used

```
make install
```

will be created an new folder in /opt/glibc

and using

```
sudo make install
```

will be created an new folder in /3/glibc

trying run ldd --version

show

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31

running /3/glibc/glibc-2.35-install/bin/ldd --version

show

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31

After trying start bfors show again the same error message

```
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by ./bforartists)
./bforartists: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /opt/bforartists-3.5.0-linux/lib/libcycles_kernel_oneapi_aot.so)
```

I have edit /etc/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/glibc/lib:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

bforartists continue not reading glibc2.35.

I had done the command

```
make uninstall
```

show the message

```
make -r PARALLELMFLAGS="" -C /tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35 objdir=`pwd` uninstall

make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35'

make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.

make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35'

make: *** [Makefile:9: uninstall] Error 2
```

I am new Linux user ...  I not understand if is possible have the OS libc2.31 in OS library and in same time another libc version in alternate path configured to some softwares.

After of installed need configure any path variable to softwares read that libc new compiled version ?
Not is possible install an glibc alternate version in same OS libc ?

When is done the command
/tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35/configure --prefix=$tmp/3/glibc/glibc-2.35-install
is done any changes of file written in OS directoires in / root ?

How uninstall that compiled version ? Only removing the new created directory or was written files in others paths too ? was done any changes in OS settings files ?

Thanks for using your time reading that topic.
Have an nice day.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?  A fully upgrade 20.04 system has reported itself as 20.04.6 & not 20.04.5 for some weeks now, so if you're using Ubuntu ensure you've applied all security fixes (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded late in the week before that ISO release)

Comment: guiverc ? you here ? All good with you ? I remember your posts in Lubuntu forum =) .... Using Lubuntu 20.04 totally updated and being 20.04.6 ... libc version is 6_2.31 ... I not see if have an libc6-2.35 in deb file format to be installled ... however need update in several others files .... in moment for me is as if is possible have libc6_2.35 is compiling in an alternate path ... I not understand because not work and how unistall ... thanks for reply